# Efficient way to handle JS function ordering

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JS and am still slightly confused, by the ordering and nesting of JS functions. I have a script that I want to occur in a specific way. The problem a criteria can be left blank by a user. Im trying to say if the variable length is greater than zero run the callback, but then move into the code that occurs under the next two if statements. I know there must be a more efficient method for this, but for the life of me I can't think of one besides placing all the other code under each different if/else statement.

```
var lst = []
var lst2 = []
var lst3 = []

alert(cityu);
alert(dateu);
alert(numberu);

d3.csv("kyle.csv", function (d) {
    return {
        city: d.from,
        number: d.phone_number,
        date: d.from_date
    };
}, function (error, rows) {
    if (dateu.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (rows[i].date === dateu) {
                lst.push(rows[i]);
                console.log(rows[i]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (cityu.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < lst.city.length; i++) {
                if (lst.city[i] === cityu) {
                    lst2.push(lst[i]);
                    console.log(lst2);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (numberu.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    if (lst.number[i] === numberu) {
                        lst3.push(lst2[i]);
                        console.log(lst3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
};
```

Here you can see that if the dateu variable has length greater than zero the rows in a csv matching that user entered criteria will be pushed to the array "lst". Obviously it currently doesn't move into the next callback under, it will only do this if "dateu" equalled zero.

One other issue with my script is that at each if statement I hope to reduce my original input based on the user entered parameters. For example a user might enter "seattle" the variable "city" will now equal seattle and only rows containing Seattle as their city will be kept in the array that rows[i] is pushed to.

Every piece of user input shown here:

```
alert(cityu);
alert(dateu);
alert(numberu);
```

will have the same affect on the dataset, each time reducing the number of rows included.

The problem specifically is that each if statement relies on the array from the previous callback.

Comment: Do you expect more than one of `dateu`, `cityu` and `numberu` to be greater than zero during each iteration? What is the expected result?

Comment: Thank you and yes, one of these variables will always be more than zero. Basically the end result is it matches based on the input to a row in a csv which is used to create a d3 graphic. No input no graphic.

Comment: `move into the next function` - do you mean after the `} else {` - that's not a new function

Comment: @JaromandaX of course you're right, that is what I'm referring to. I'll make that edit

Comment: Are there essentially only three paths to take?

Comment: @allin Yep only three user inputs, there could be all three filled in or only one. I would prefer it stay in the same order as it will return the most filtered results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code redone a little - I've removed the else blocks, because you want to do each loop regardless of the previous loop

```
if(condition1) {
    do something
}
else {
    do something else
}
```

from that, if the first condition is met, the else block wont get executed

```
if(condition1) {
    do something
}
if(condition2) {
    do something else
}
```

In this case, `do something else` only relies on condition2 being true, consition1 is irrelevant

```
    var lst = []
    var lst2 = []
    var lst3 = []

    alert(cityu);
    alert(dateu);
    alert(numberu);

    d3.csv("kyle.csv", function(d) {
        return {
            city: d.from,
            number: d.phone_number,
            date: d.from_date
        };
    }, function(error, rows) {
        var i;
        if (dateu.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                if (rows[i].date === dateu) {
                    lst.push(rows[i]);
                    console.log(rows[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        if (cityu.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < lst.city.length; i++) {
                if (lst.city[i] === cityu) {
                    lst2.push(lst[i]);
                    console.log(lst2);
                }
            }
        }
        if (numberu.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                if (lst.number[i] === numberu) {
                    lst3.push(lst2[i]);
                    console.log(lst3);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

One minor inconsequential change, moved the declaration of `var i` to the top of the function block, because technically you were declaring it three times, and jslint/jshint would complain - though nothing would break (yet)

Comment: Okay, I knew there had to be a simpler way. There is only one thing this code doesn't solve. Each if statement relies on the previous array, because the original csv is being reduced at each level. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: I've just looked deeply into the code in each loop, and my answer wont fix the issue there I'm afraid - I really have no idea what you are trying to achieve - best give an example of input data, and expected output data in your question

Comment: Okay, I can make that edit, but still thank you so much!

Comment: @NelsCarlson JaromandaX [Nest the if statements inside of each other](https://gist.github.com/humbleRumble/e4859e4560b2e2ab1ed9)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm still not completely sure on your logic, but looking at Tiny Giant's gist, it seems like there are only three combinations:</strike>

1) Only `dateu` exists.

2) `dateu` and `cityu` exist.

3) `dateu`, `cityu`, and `numberu` exist.

So you don't care about the condition where `dateu` and `numberu` exist, but `cityu` is empty, right?

**Okay**, I reread your code. It seems like you have rows, and you have three possible filters. Filter rows based on `AND`, for example `cityu AND dateu`.

If so, here's a giant refactor. Just as a note, there may be some JavaScript errors because I had no way of testing this. But the code is fairly simple and straightforward:

```
var lst = []  // I'm not using these.
var lst2 = []
var lst3 = []

alert(cityu);
alert(dateu);
alert(numberu);

var getActiveFilters = function() {
  // Edit possibleFilters as necessary.
  // the key should reflect the header of the column
  // and the value is a variable referring to the user-inputted string

  var possibleFilters = {
    'date': dateu,
    'city': cityu,
    'number': numberu
  };

  var activeFilters = {};

  for (key in possibleFilters) {
    if (possibleFilters[key].length > 0) {
      activeFilters[key] = possibleFilters[key];
    }
  }

  return activeFilters;
}

// just made this into a function to get it out of the callback
var functionAfterCsv = function(rows) {
  var activeFilters = getActiveFilters();

  var filteredList = [];
  var addRow = false;

  for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    // see if the current row matches all the filters present
    for (key in activeFilters) {
      if (rows[i][key] === activeFilters[key]) {
        addRow = true;
      } else {
        addRow = false;
        // if the row doesn't meet one of the conditions,
        // there's no need to check the rest
        break;
      }
    }

    if (addRow) {
      filteredList.push(row[i]);
    }
  }

  return filteredList;
};

d3.csv("kyle.csv", function (d) {
    return {
        city: d.from,
        number: d.phone_number,
        date: d.from_date
    };
  }, function (error, rows) {
    functionAfterCsv(rows);
  })
});
```

If you're filtering using `OR`, then you'll need to change your comparison to something like this:

```
for (key in activeFilters) {
  if (rows[i][key] === activeFilters[key]) {
    addRow = true;
    break;  // if one is true, that's good enough for an OR
  } else {
    addRow = addRow || false;
  }
}

if (addRow) {
  filteredList.push(row[i]);
  // reset addRow for the next row
  addRow = false;
}
```

Hope this was closer to your intended logic!

Comment: Oh, Im sorry if I was unclear, but any of the three variables could be filled while the others remain blank. This is an interesting take, but considering the variability in user input, it would end up being pretty long.

Comment: @NelsCarlson I just re-read your code and re-wrote my response. Is is closer to your idea?